# Oracle Form Personalization

Tags: sql, oracle, validation, plsql, oracleforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTPcf.png)

I'm having a problem with form personalization,I'm a beginner in oracle 
EBS and Forms.i need to do validation in HR module when the user is accessing the end employment form and trying to terminate the user.
when the end-user is clicking on the TERMINATE button then it should check the condition and if the condition is null then it should through an error message.

I'm using these condition

```
select 'Y'
from dual
where exists (select 'Y'
              from pa_expenditure_items_all paei,
                   pa_expenditures_all pae
              where paei.expenditure_id = pae.expenditure_id and
                    pae.incurred_by_person_id  = : person_id and
                    cost_distributed_flag = 'N'
             )
```

Comment: If you have a question, then you should ask it.

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this, I presume:

```
declare
   l_yes  varchar2 (1);
begin
   select max ('Y')
     into l_yes
     from dual
    where exists
             (select 'Y'
                from pa_expenditure_items_all paei, pa_expenditures_all pae
               where     paei.expenditure_id = pae.expenditure_id
                     and pae.incurred_by_person_id = :person_id
                     and cost_distributed_flag = 'N');

   if l_yes is null
   then
      message ('Condition is not met');
      raise form_trigger_failure;
   else
      -- Do something; probably terminate that user
      null;
   end if;
end;
```

Comment: Hi LittleFoot Can you please provide me full navigations.  i used your query still getting error

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not. I don't know EBS and its procedures. Code I posted works in Forms (Builder), but that's more or less all I can do for you. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In the "conditions" field, you don't put a whole query.  You just put a Boolean expression (such as you would put in the `WHERE` clause of a query).

So, instead of what you've got, try this:

```
exists (select 'Y'
        from pa_expenditure_items_all paei,
             pa_expenditures_all pae
        where paei.expenditure_id = pae.expenditure_id and
              pae.incurred_by_person_id  = :person_id and
              cost_distributed_flag = 'N'
       )
```

The `:person_id` assumes that `PERSON_ID` is a field in the block that your Forms trigger is firing on.  Better to use the `:block.field` form to make it a little more explicit.

Comment: Hi matthew these is the field :PERIOD_OF_PLACEMENT.TERMINATE and :person_id is parameter

Comment: That's fine too, so `:parameter.person.id`.  I expect you have several problems here, not just putting the wrong thing in the conditions field.  You should update your post with an actual problem and question.